# Append or prepend to array without VBA/UDF

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

In Excel, is there a built-in formula/function to append or prepend a value to an array?  So suppose I have my own UDF, MyFunc(...) that returns an array of values.  Can I append or preprend a single value to this result using a reference to a single cell?

Comment: AFAIK, no formula can do this and there are no `append` function in VBA. Yet, you could use the `ConcatenateArrays` function from [Chris Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm)

Comment: JMax - thanks for the pointer!  I took a look at ConcatenateArrays and its exactly what I want to accomplish (I just have to wrap that function with my own function that returns the resulting array, instead of boolean true/false).  Could you post this as the answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: If its a single value why dont you just Redim Preserve the array with 1 more element, and then add it rather than run ConcatenateArrays?

Comment: Actually I think InsertElementIntoArray does this.

Comment: @SFun28: you should have a look at Chris' answer. If it suits better, you'd probably better accept his answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, here is a possible answer:

AFAIK, no formula can do this and there are no append function in VBA. Yet, you could use the `ConcatenateArrays` function from [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm)

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using standard Excel array functions.

For illustration, lets assume MyFunc is

```
Function MyFunc(r As Range) As Variant
    MyFunc = r.Value
End Function
```

Where the passed range is more than one cell, this returns a two-dimensional array.

When entered as an array formula like `=D1&MyFunc(A2:C7)&E1` this prepends D1 and appends E1

It can also be used in a standard non-array formula, where an array parameter is expected, as shown in cell D12 below

[image]

Comment: Nice one! This also reminds me of [this article (from Chip Pearson again](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ReturningArraysFromVBA.aspx) where he explains how to return and use an array from a UDF

Comment: Chris - I've tried the following: =SUM({1,2,3,4}) and of course that returns 10.  However, =SUM({1,2,3,4}&A1) where A1 is a numeric returns 0.  This is the case regardless of whether the formula is entered as an array formula.  thoughts?

Comment: Chris - I think you're proposing string concatenation to each element of the array instead of appending a single element to the whole array?

Comment: The reason `=SUM({1,2,3,4}&A1)` returns 0 is & is string concatination.  Try `Sum({1,2,3,4}+A1)` = 14

Comment: Yes. My example demo'd string concatination because that is how I interpreted your question.  Other operators may also be used.  If you explain a little more about what you are trying to do i might be able to help more

Comment: Chris - I'm simply trying to append or prepend a value to an array =)  So imagine you have an excel array with 5 items {1,2,3,4,5}.  I'm trying to add an item to that array either at the beginning or end.  So the resulting array may look like {6,1,2,3,4,5} or {1,2,3,4,5,6} if I'm trying to prepend or append 6.  It sounds like there is no built-in way to do this and that I need to use a UDF such as Chip Pearson's InsertElementIntoArray